# Creating a bootstrap popover on click of a button with dynamic content and dismiss when click again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page where there is a jquery grid and a link with and icon. I need to show a popover and show a form inside the popover. But the popover should close when the user clicks on another link (another popover should appear) or anywhere else on the page except the popover.

The current code I have written does not work.

Current code:

HTML Code for link (This div is a column in the grid and rowid will be different for each row):

```
<div rowid="5" class="action-buttons">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="blue editRow">
       <i class="icon-pencil bigger-130"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="green markComplete">
       <i class="icon-check bigger-130"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
$('#grid-table').on('click','.editRow',function(e){
    $(this).popover({
        html: true,
        title: 'Popover Title<a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>',
        content: '<a>This one works fine!!</a>' //Content can change based on rowId
    });
    $(this).popover('show');
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('body').click(function (e) {
        if (($('.popover').has(e.target).length == 0) || $(e.target).is('.close')) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: could you please make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should write the following code outside of `.editRow` click event:

```
$('body').click(function (e) {
        if (($('.popover').has(e.target).length == 0) || $(e.target).is('.close')) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Actually the grid table div is loaded using an ajax call and there could be a scenario that .popover or .editRow will not be available at that time. After putting this code outside .editRow click event, it is not even showing the popover.